# loop through folder and find files missing python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through a folder for a given date. There will be 3-4 files in a folder everyday. I have to check if each file is present in the folder for a given date. I cannot hardcode the file name because it has sequence number and can vary.

I got below snippet from stackoverflow and it works if my filename is consistent.

```
import glob

source='./'
date=20221102
paths=["file1_"+date+"*.json","file2_"+date+"*.json","file3_"+date+"*.json"]
for path in paths:
        print(f"looking for {path} with {source+'**/'+path+'.jpg'}")
        print(glob.glob(source+"**/"+path+".jpg",recursive=True))
mp=[path for path in paths if not glob.glob(source+"**/"+path+".jpg",recursive=True)]
for nl in mp:
      print(f'{nl}... is missing')
```

I just would like to loop all files in a folder and throw exception if any one of the file is missing.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: "I have to check if each file is present". This doesn't make sense to me. If the file is there, it is present. I think you mean that the files in the folder have to match certain conditions, but you haven't stated what those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I handle the issue. I grab a list of files from path that contain the date and file type. I then split on any possible delimiter that isn't alphanumeric to create a list of lists. Then flatten to a single list.
Finally compare lists for matches return boolean.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path


def flatten_nested(nested: list or tuple or set) -> list:
    flattened = []
    [flattened.extend(flatten_nested(x)) if isinstance(x, (list, tuple, set)) else flattened.append(x) for x in nested]

    return flattened


def find_files(file_path: str, file_type: str, value: str) -> list:
    files = Path(file_path).rglob(f"*{value}*.{file_type}")
    delimiter = r"(?<=[^\W_])[\W_]+(?=[^\W_])"

    return flatten_nested([re.sub(delimiter, " ", x.stem).split(" ") for x in files if x.is_file()])


source = "./"
to_check = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
check = all(x in find_files(source, "json", "20221102") for x in to_check)

print(check)

True
```